# Chemical Engineering Question using Raoult's Law

Tags: chemical-engineering

A liquid mixture containing 35.0 mole% acetone and 65.0 mole% water is to be partially vaporized to produce a vapor that is 70.0 mole% acetone and a residual liquid that is 30.0 mole% acetone.

(a) Suppose the process is to be carried out continuously, and at steady state the feed rate to the evaporator is 10.0 kmol/h. Calculate the molar flow rates of the product streams and the temperature (°C) and pressure (mm Hg) of the system.

How do you calculate the temperature and the pressure?

Comment: As this looks like a homework question, you should show what you have tried, where you think you are going wrong : this is not a “we do your homework” service...